# Creating jdbc connections for multiple databases-Need advice in designing it

Tags: java, jdbc

I have requirement where I need to read data from multiple rdbms tables which are present different databases. I have a regular connection class which returns a connection from its getConnection() method as below.

```
public class DbManager {
    private static Connection connection;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            if(connection == null) { 
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:portnumber", "username", "password");
                return connection;
            } else { 
                return connection;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private DbManager() {
    }
}
```

But this works only for one database. I have multiple databases in MySql, Oracle, Postgres and I have to read all the tables in all of those databases.
Is there a way to create connections for multiple databases using the same class or is there a different way to implement that ?

Comment: try using factory patter and pass database name as a parameter

Comment: tons of ways. you can add several static Connections and create a getConnection() method that takes a parameter to pick the right DB, or a separate getConnection() method for each DB, or overwrite the connection variable each time you create a new connection ...
a lot depends on your requirements and whether or not different db's can be called at the same time.

Comment: Include required driver managers. Then change `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` and `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:portnumber"` accordingly.

Comment: Just use different URLs for different databases. The `Class.forName()` is useless with modern drivers. The driver manager will automatically detect the correct driver based on the JDBC URL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you give a reference to your suggestion, so that I can understand the logic behind it.

Comment: [JDBC 4.1 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf) chapter "4.1 Establishing a Connection": "*DriverManager
 will automatically load any JDBC drivers 
found within the CLASSPATH*"

Comment: [JavaDocs for DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html): "*Applications no longer need to explicitly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName()*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Important caveat: it will only automatically load drivers on the system classpath, drivers loaded later (eg bundled in a WAR), will still need to be loaded explicitly.

Comment: Just don't hardcode the driver name and URL and you should have a starting point. For the rest, this is too broad, and very context-specific what is the 'best' solution for you.